# html canvas smooth movement

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been breaking my head for a while over this now. I wrote a space game in javascript using the canvas. I use a 800x600 resolution with 16x16 tiles and I have around 200-300 tiles in the viewport at any moment.

Ofcourse this would be too slow to redraw every frame So I render it to an offscreen canvas that is 1 tile bigger on every side. When moving I just shift the offscreen canvas and only redraw the new tiles. This works perfectly at 60fps, even with 1000+ tiles. There is only a minor glitch, moving around is not 100% smooth.

I can't explain whats happening, it's some kind of jumpy movement/screen tearing.
I though it was some bug in my code, but when I created a simple test with 1 tile, I have the exact same bug.

Here is my test: http://jsfiddle.net/da7g9khj/1/

```js
var prevTime = new Date().getTime();
function loop(time) {
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);

  var curTime = new Date().getTime();
  var dt = (curTime - prevTime) / 1000;
  prevTime = curTime;


  var speed = 6;
  if(keys.up) camera.y -= speed * dt;
  if(keys.down) camera.y += speed * dt;
  if(keys.left) camera.x -= speed * dt;
  if(keys.right) camera.x += speed * dt;

  var leftMost = (camera.x - scn.width / 2);
  var topMost = (camera.y - scn.height / 2);
  var screenCoordinates = {
      x: (300 - leftMost) * 16,
      y: (250 - topMost) * 16
  };

  rsc.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, scn.width * 16, scn.height * 16);

  rsc.ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  rsc.ctx.beginPath();   

  rsc.ctx.rect(Math.round(screenCoordinates.x), Math.round(screenCoordinates.y), 16, 16);

  rsc.ctx.fill();
  rsc.ctx.closePath();      
}

var camera = {x: 300, y: 250}
var rsc = {};
var scn = {
  width: 50,
  height: 37.5
};
var keys = {
  up: false,
  down: false,
  right: false,
  left: false
};

rsc.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
rsc.canvas.width = 16 * scn.width;
rsc.canvas.height = 16 * scn.height;
rsc.ctx = rsc.canvas.getContext("2d");

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
  switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 40:
          keys.down = true;
          return false;
      case 38:
          keys.up = true;
          return false;
      case 37:
          keys.left = true;
          return false;
      case 39:
          keys.right = true;
          return false;
  }
};

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
  switch(e.keyCode) {
      case 40:
          keys.down = false;
          return false;
      case 38:
          keys.up = false;
          return false;
      case 37:
          keys.left = false;
          return false;
      case 39:
          keys.right = false;
          return false;
  }
};

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Try moving the camera with the arrow keys. Hold a key down, and you should sometimes see jumpy movement.

I really hope someone can help me with this, cause i've been trying to find out why this is happening for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

On my desktop I get the normal semi-smooth movement of your rectangle, but no jumping or tearing.  I'm guessing the problem occurs on devices with less resources available than a good desktop.

Your code looks fairly efficient but I do see quite a bit of cruft in your animation loop--but that wouldn't cause your jumps and tears.

Here's a less crufty refactoring (won't fix your problems):  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/0k2Ljth5/

What's probably causing your jumping is `var dt = (curTime - prevTime) / 1000;`.  If requestAnimationFrame cannot execute the loop for some reason (usually caused some other system task that's taking time), then your `dt` will be larger than expected and your rect will "jump" over the expected position to the position dictated by the larger `dt`.

On the other hand, tears are caused by previous drawings that are incomplete at the time a new loop frame begins.  The amount of drawing you're asking for does not always fit in the loop.  The cure to tearing is to reduce the work that the canvas must do during a loop.

Comment: Mhm its weird tho, I have the same jerky movement on my netbook and my pretty powerfull desktop. And a friend of me has the same problem on a mac pro which is even more powerfull :p.
I am using linux tho, ill give it a try on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to decrease the speed at which the object moves, but increase the rate at which the canvas redraws the square? Usually I find that my slow or non-smooth movement issues can be fixed simple by increasing the rate at which the canvas redraws, but slowing the speed so it keeps the same speed.